# Collection in C++

Tags: c++

I have written a generic `Collection` class which allows me to add and remove items from an encapsulated `std::list`. The collection will raise an event when an item has been added or removed.

Normally I would have derived this class from the `std::list`, but I have been strongly recommended against doing so for various reasons. I still need to be able to iterate over the collection, however, and one way of doing so was exposing `begin` and `end` methods, returning a vanilla STL iterator:

```
template <typename T>
class Collection
{
public:
    typename std::list<T*>::iterator begin()
    {
        return _items.begin();
    }

    void Add(T* item)
    {
        _items.push_back(item);

        ...
    }

private:

    std::list<T*> _items;
};
```

Is this a proper way of encapsulating an STL container while retaining the ability to iterate over it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

But you also want to expose the types of the iterator:

```
template <typename T>
class Collection
{
    // Since we are going to mention the container type
    // in multiple places actually give it a shorter name.
    // This also helps if you change the container type
    // as you only have to change the type in one place.
    typedef typename std::list<T*>        Cont;
  public:
    // Expose your iterator types.
    // That way people don't need to know that you are
    // using a list (thus allowing you to change it in the future)
    // to use your iterators.
    typedef typename Cont::iterator       iterator;
    typedef typename Cont::const_iterator const_iterator;


    // Now iterators can use your types.
    iterator       begin()       {items.begin();}
    iterator       end()         {items.end();}

    // Sometimes also useful to expose the const versions.
    const_iterator begin() const {items.begin();}
    const_iterator end()   const {items.end();}        

    void Add(T* item)
    {
        items.push_back(item);
    }

  private:

    Cont items;
};
```

#### Other notes:

Be careful using a '_' as the first character of an identifier. Most of them are reserved and unless you know all the rules (and everybody in your company does) you may accidentally end up in hot water.

PS. You are OK with `_items`. I just prefer never to use them (As the first character).

Container class are designed to hold objects, but you are storing pointers.
The question now becomes who owns the pointer (as they are responsible for deleting the pointer). This is compounded by your add() interface which also passes a pointer.

In modern C++ you very rarely see RAW pointers being passed around.

How we change the interface will depend on how you expect it to be used. But I assume you are dynamically allocating the object and passing the ownership to the container. In this case I would change the interface to:

```
void add(std::unique_ptr<T> item)
// C++03 does not have std::unique_ptr you will need to use std::auto_ptr
// void add(std::auto_ptr<T> item)
//    Basically it is the same thing but the unique_ptr requires an explicit move.
```

This indicates to the reader and the container that you are passing ownership to the container and it is responsible for deleting the pointer. Note: you will now have to make sure that the destructor correctly destroys the pointers. Also note that because you define the destructor to do some real work you also need to make sure you obey the rule of three (as the default copy constructor and assignment operator will not work correctly).

All this has been encapsulated in the boost ptr container(s).

Take a look at:

```
boost::ptr_list<T>
```

This is a list that holds pointers to `T` and as such the items are correctly polymorphic. The container takes ownership of the pointers and will correctly destroy them when the container is destroyed. And finally the container exposes its members via reference to the underlying object and thus works very well with the std:: algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input! I will be wrapping the iterators and it was not my intentiont of giving ownership to the collection, so I will take to not to pass raw pointers around. Thanks!

Comment: If you are **NOT** giving ownership to the collection. Then the interface should be designed to accept a reference not a pointer. You can store a pointer in the list but it should be passed as a reference to the Collection.